# Keywords in UDLs in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, keyword

I recently made a User Defined Language in Notepad++, when I enter a keyword, it gets highlighted, but only if it is followed by a space. Some of the keywords will be followed by a comma, or enclosed in parentheses, but I still want them to be highligOted, is there a way of doing this?
Here's an example:

foo , bar 
Both are highlighted

foo, bar
Only bar is highlighted

Comment: How did you resolved this, even I'm facing the same issue, could you please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

Add each variation to the UDL "Operators and Delimiters" list, as follows:

- Click Language => Define Your Language
- Click Keywords Lists
- Add `foo` to 1st Group
- Click Styler
- Select the color
- Click OK
- Click Operators and Delimiters
- Add `,` to Operators 1 style
- Click Styler
- Select the color
- Click Save

Comment: When i add ","  to Delimiter 1, and color black, it just colors everything black from the first comma onwards.
Should i be adding something to the "escape" and "close" box in delimiters?

Comment: You can move the comma to Operators1 instead